# Android: software for perfoming desktop-initiated rsync-like downloads from Android to desktop?

Tags: android, file-synchronization

I know that I can use adb from my desktop computer to take a backup of my sdcard ...

```
adb pull /sdcard/ .
```

This downloads everything from my sdcard to the specified directory on my desktop machine. However, I'm wondering if there is some non-adb software that I can use for downloading in an rsync-like manner: *i.e.*, only downloading and updating files that have actually changed between my device's sdcard and the directory on the desktop machine.

Specifically, I want to initiate the download from the desktop machine, *not* from from my Android device, so the software I desire would have to allow this kind of desktop-initiated file transfer.

Any ideas?

PS: This is an Android-10 device, a OnePlus 7Pro (GM-1917) running OOS 10.3.2. However, the answer to my question is probably unrelated to that, since it has to do more with `adb` than the android device itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! If you are looking for [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), you'd better ask at our sister-site Android.SE. If you're looking for software, please **[edit]** your question and [add missing details](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) like the OS on your host (the "receiving end" of your pull example), what features you neeed (e.g. GUI/CLI), how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions, etc. Thanks!

Comment: I'll re-ask in the sister site. Lately I've noticed that there is a much higher likelihood that any given question will be redirected somewhere else. I understand the motivation for setting things up this way, but it has a side-effect of making things more inconvenient for people who have serious, sincere questions to ask and who happen to overlook one or more of the newer details of question acceptability. I was directed *here* for a similar question that I previously asked in that same sister site, so it isn't always easy to know which site is the most "acceptable".

Comment: This is the question that originally posted in the sister site, but which I was told to post here, instead. Notice that it was upvoted and I got 10 points for it: 
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74334/android-selectively-blocking-toast-popups-without-xposed
What is different between that question and this one, which would allow one of them here and disallow the other?
This is a sincere question. I want to understand the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer – as that's also asking for a howto, it's off-topic as well (upvote or not). As for the inconvenience: that's how SE works, using specific "stacks". But as I wrote: if you can re-phrase your question here to ask for software, it can co-exist with your asking for a howto on Android.SE, giving you the best of both worlds. Same for the other question you've linked.

Comment: OK. I reworded this question. As for the other, earlier question, it gave me 10 points, but I'll go back to it a little later today and see if I can do any rewording. If certain questions are off topic, they shouldn't give me points ... correct? I'm not talking about upvote points.

Comment: Then I don't know what points you're talking about. Users tend to upvote quite obvious off-topic questions as well, that can hardly be controlled. And the badge system doesn't know anything about on-topic – it just "counts stuff" like posts, votes etc.